# Need to run TestNG suites and tests in parallel

Tags: testng, selenium-grid

I have 3 test NG files.
Machine1.xml:

```
<suite name="Machine1" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
<test name="LoginTest">
<classes>
<class name="test.app.home.LoginTest"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Machine2.xml

```
<suite name="Machine2" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
<test name="LoginTest">
<classes>
<class name="test.app.home.LoginTest"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

MachineMain.xml

```
<suite name="testng" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<tests>
<test name="Machine1">
<suite-files> 
<suite-file path="Machine1.xml"/> 
</suite-files>
</test>
<test name="Machine2">
<suite-files> 
<suite-file path="Machine2.xml"/> 
</suite-files>
</test>
</tests>
</suite>
```

Note: I am running the MachineMain.xml through eclipse. I have written the code to open the remoteWebDriver inside setup method and i have @BeforeSuite annotation just above the setup method.

What i am trying: I have a hub and 2 nodes, both the nodes have maxInstance as 1. I am trying to run the 2 xml - Machine1.xml and Machine2.xml (Suites) in parallel by opening one browser in each node - Basically Machine1.xml suite in one node (Machine 1) and Machine2.xml suite in the other node (Machine 2).

What is happeing: The hub sends first Machine1.xml request to one Node (Machine 1) and after it finishes the execution, the second Machine2.xml is picked and sent to second Node (Machine 2).

I was expecting that since i have specifed 'suite-file' inside 'test' tag and specified "parallel" value to 'tests' and "thread-count" value to 2 in MachineMain.xml, it would automatically execute the suites in parallel.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: You are running the same test from two xmls?? If you can tell the actual testing requirement, we can perhaps suggest a solution.

Comment: The actual requirement is that i will be running the same test suite against different IE versions which are in different machines. So if i have to run the suite against IE11 and IE10 alone, then i would have 2 test tags with one test tag having the suite-file path as the xml which will have parameters for IE11 and the other test tag for IE10. So, I will have xml(s) with different parameter readily available and as per the requirement, i will include/exclude the suite-file path in the main xml.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two xml for your requirement.  Follow these steps and you should have same test running parallel.

I am assuming that since you have grid setup done, you aware of desiredcapabilities.  If not refer this link https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

1. Create two tests in one testng xml and have a parameter for browser version for each test. Keep parallel = tests, thread count = 2 in suite tag.
2. Use the version in capabilities object in your setup method so that it matches the node configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I tired this earlier and while it allows me to have test execution in parallel, the problem I faced with this set up is

I have about 10 components to test. I have written the sctipt to test these in 10 seperate class. I have an abstract class which has all the commonly used methods and I extend this abstract class from all the 10 classes. 
The problem is that the first class included with in the test tag is able to access the global variable of the abstarct class but the second class mentioned in the same test tag read it as null. below is the XML for your refrence

Comment: <suite name="Machine1" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
    <test name="LoginTest" parallel="false">
 <classes>
       <class name="test.app.home.LoginTest"/>
       <class name="test.app.home.comp1Test"/>
 </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Comment: Also, I have a method in the abstract classwhich will return the webelement - this method when called from first class works fine but when called from second class, it is not able to find the element and infact in the method, i have a wait of 20 seconds to find the element but it does not wait for even 2 seconds. Also, another method in the abstract class which takes the screen shot works for the first class but when called from second class, it throws nullpointerexception.

Comment: Without looking at full code, cannot suggest any solution. Have a look at this article and use ThreadLocal idea and see if  it helps --http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/